# Angular 2 Routing Behaviour

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using angular 2 routing in my test project. Already created routing.ts and imported it in Module.ts.

In my app.component.html(which is template html file for app.component.ts)
I have the following code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Application name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="en/test" routerLinkActive="active">Test1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    Something
    <hr />

    <div>
        <a routerLink="en/test" routerLinkActive="active">Test2</a>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

However, when I launch application, Test1 generates following `<a>` tag:

Test1:

```
<a routerlink="en/test" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="en/test" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" ng-reflect-href="/en/home/en/test" href="/en/home/en/test">Test1</a>
```

and Test2:

```
<a routerlink="en/test" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="en/test" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" ng-reflect-href="/en/test" href="/en/test">Test2</a>
```

As you can see the difference is among `ng-reflect-href` and `href` attributes.
Test1: `ng-reflect-href="/en/home/en/test" href="/en/home/en/test"`
Test2: `ng-reflect-href="/en/test" href="/en/test"`

My question is: Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed this by adding `/` in routerLink before `"en/test"`
It's like this now:

```
<li><a routerLink="/en/test" routerLinkActive="active">Test1</a></li>
```